# i'm new in the platform and also new programming. I'm learning callback and i have this excersice that i cannot undesrstand how to aproche it

Tags: javascript, web, callback

you must create a function called **callback** that receives as a parameter a **number** and a **function**. this function must return the result of that function giving as an argument the parameter **number**

Examples..

// - callback(5, (num)=>{return num*10}) should return 50
// - callback(25, (num)=>{return num/5}) should return 5

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asking you to create a function, like:

```
const todo = () => {}
```

that executes a callback using the parameter to the function as the parameter to the callback, an example being:

```
const todo = (a, b) => {
   // call method b using a as parameter
}
```

If you still can't find the answer, leave me a comment and I will help you out some more.

Comment: I do get how to call the method, but when i have to get the result, where should i do the math?

example.  method a (* 10)

Comment: @NachoRodriguez You would return the callback, 'b', called with the perimeter 'a', from the function 'todo.' There is no adding to do on your part, only in the calling of 'todo.'

Comment: I really apreciate your answer, to anyone asking, this is a basic example of calling back sth.